# Android - calculate dimensions from activity before measurement

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

My activity shall have a screen divided into two sections. The first will hold custom view that occupies as much space as possible. The second section holds matrix of buttons. I do not their number at design time, I want to create them in `Activity` based on screen size and other conditions (easy level will have less buttons).

[image]

I currently use `LinearLayout`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:id="@+id/puzzleScreen"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <lelisoft.com.lelimath.view.TilesView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tiles" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/choices">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="6"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="23"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

`TilesView` had consumed complete screen until I overriden `onMeasure()`. To continue I have to calculate available space, number of buttons and divide space between both sections and pass this information to `TilesView` and `LayoutManagers`. Unfortunatelly `onCreate()` is not correct location for this calculation as I cannot figure out dimensions of root view (getters return 0).

Where is the correct place in Activity lifecycle where to get dimensions and create all buttons dynamically? It seems to me like chicken-egg problem.

**UPDATE**

I tried to debug other methods: `onStart()` and `onResume()` return 0, then measurement is called and finally `onCreateOptionsMenu()` receives coordinates. Too late.

**UPDATE 2**

The question is how to find dimensions of the contentView from Activity before measurement. I can get `getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay()`, but it contains action bar etc.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle state) {
    super.onCreate(state);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_puzzle);
    View puzzleView = findViewById(R.id.puzzleScreen);
    // todo get maximum width and height for R.layout.activity_puzzle
```

Comment: Did you try doing the calculations in onCreateView() ?

Comment: There is no such method in Activity

Comment: Ah sorry then, that's where I create my complex layouts dynamically, but I use fragments.

Comment: you should also show you java code, to make a transparency in problem.

Comment: did you also try to use simple weights in xml layout

Comment: I have not advanced to Fragments yet. Custom View code is in my previous question. Code from onCreate() is not interesting when we know it does not work. I have not used weights yet because I will need precisely calculated and fixed height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you know exactly how many rows the bottom matrix has?

You could set the `android:layout_weight="1"` and `android:layout_height="0px"`
to tell the `ViewGroup` that your customView will occupy all the remaining space excluding the Button Matrix.

Comment: It looks promising, thank you. The second section is displayed now. But I have to calculate number of tiles in the first section which corresponds to number of buttons in the second section. I cannot imagine how to do it if I do not know width and height of the screen.

Comment: Do you already know how to get the width and height of the screen? My little suggestion is that you could store your height and width into a static variable in the Application class, so that you just have to calculate once. You could combine the two view into 1 more custom view and implement laying out the views your self (overriding onMeasure()).

Comment: I updated my question. I can get display size but it is somewhat bigger than actual content view dimensions.

Comment: You could get the ActionBarHeight from the theme. 56dp on phones

Comment: Here you are. 
        TypedArray a = getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(R.style.AppTheme, new int[] {R.attr.actionBarSize});
        int attributeResourceId = a.getResourceId(0, 0);
        a.recycle();

Comment: R.style.AppTheme is your Activity or Application Theme, you can find your theme in your AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: Nexus 5: display height 1184, actionBarHeight 112, remainder is 1072. I commented out the second section so there is only one view and it got 1022. There is 50 pixels missing - bottom bar?

Comment: the status bar i think :D

Comment: I found a solution - to have custom view that renders both sections!

Comment: Yeah great! By the way, Status bar height is an attribute of the theme that can be get the same way as actionBarHeight.

Comment: I searched all attribues with *size* in its name and I have not found it.

Comment: Sorry, I am wrong. I guess we can not find it without hacking.

Answer (score 1):

For your first question:

In onCreate() lifeCycle ,you can not get the dimensions.
Because your the all view have not measured()!

I always use view.post() to get the dimension() in onCreate() method;

```
 view.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            view.getMeasuredHeight();
        }
    });
```

For your second question:

On the bottom section,I think you should use custom view extends ViewGroup.Override constructor、onMeasure()、onLayout():

```
public class TextBlocksView extends ViewGroup {}
```

In constructor, you add LinearLayout(orientation:horizontal) as much as Line Number,and add each item(addView() method and layoutParams weight 1!!)  ....

```
public TextBlocksView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    this.removeAllViews();
    .....
    this.addView(linearLayoutView);
}
```

In onMeasure(), you calculate your dimensions in this place.(Tips:pay attention to dipToPx method！)

```
@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
    View childAt = this.getChildAt(0);
    int measuredHeight = childAt.getMeasuredHeight();
    int measuredWidth = childAt.getMeasuredWidth();
    childAt.layout(left, top, right, bottom);
    .......
}
```

in onLayout(),you place your Line item(LinearLayout orientation:horizontal)!

On the top section. you can use the same way!

My mother tongue is chinese,i am not good at english. Hope some guys edit my answer correctly! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Your english is very good! Your answer has interesting point but there is still chicken-egg dilema unsolved. I need the activity to calculate dimensions for both sections, especially the section two. The activity will create section's buttons so it cannot wait until measurements finish.